# Do multiple macro invocations initialize global structures once or multiple times?

Tags: rust, macros, initialization, rust-crates

Let we have a `proc-macro = true` crate with one or several procedural macro in it.

Let this crate with macro has a `lazy_static` variable used by the macro.

Let another crate calls macro from the first crate multiple times.

Will the initialization of the `lazy_static` variable happen once or several times during compilation of the second crate?

In short, do multiple macro invocations initialize global structures once or multiple times?

Comment: I think you need to provide some code. There are different possibly answers, depending on how things are scoped etc.

Comment: Especially in the face of language servers / IDEs evaluating macros, there's no guarantees about this at all. Don't rely on it. See also: [1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/rust/2022/12/05/what-every-rust-developer-should-know-about-macro-support-in-ides/#What_every_Rust_macro_implementor_should_take_into_account), [2](https://fasterthanli.me/articles/proc-macro-support-in-rust-analyzer-for-nightly-rustc-versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no guarantee. In general, it will be initialized once, but incremental compilation and/or IDEs may break this. So don't rely on this.